# Android prevent loading unnecessary actionbar tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I have made a FragmentPagerAdapter class

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

final int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
        case 0:


            return new PendingListFragment();
        case 1:

            return new OutgoingFragment();
        case 2:

            return new IncomingFragment();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}

}
```

And its implementation is as below-

```
private void addTabs() {
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }




    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });


}
```

It is working fine, but there is an issue, when activity load and this addTabs() method called, PendingListFragement is loaded that is needed and working as expected, but onCreate method of fragment OutoingFragment is also loaded that is not needed.
I want to prevent the loading of this class.

Please help.